# Instagram API 500 server error from Hetzner network

Tags: api, instagram

In a recent days we experience constant failure on API requestrs

```
$ curl -v https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/111111/?access_token=123234234.sdjsdjhsdfh1

<html><body><h1>500 Server Error</h1>
  An internal server error occured.
</body></html>
```

The same request made from other network versus the same IP `api.instagram.com` (forced by hosts) produces OK response always. As the token is the same that is linked to our client_id I suppose we're not Banned/Abused by someone

```
$ curl -v https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/111111/?access_token=123234234.sdjsdjhsdfh1

{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"username":".....
```

It look like Instagram put the limit to access from Hetzner network their API? 
Does anybody experience the same troubles?
Any help please!!

Comment: I have the same problems from the Hetzner network!

Comment: @ivicaa I've just checked from our server at Hetzner and the issue is still present, please report this problem at http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ maybe we will get the answer

Comment: I contacted them last sunday, but no reply yet. I am afraid, they are not enough people to handle the reports fast. I have daily around 500 people playing Instamory (my Instagram game), I am trying to compensate the 500 with caching the successful results for longer time.

Comment: For the record: my 500 Return codes are constant since yesterday. No API call to Instagram is working anymore. Always 500. Instagram support is not responding. :-( @Igor did you have more luck with this?

Comment: The service works smoothly out of hetznerand no response from Instagram.

Comment: Having the exact same issue with our servers at Hetzner. @Igor are you up and running again? With no further actions?

Comment: Just checked the Hetzner hosting and the problem is still there.

Comment: Ok. Same here. I have contacted both Hetzner and Instagram. Hetzner answered saying it's a issue with the Instagram API and Instagram has not yet answered.

Comment: Same problem here. I have several servers on Hetzner and only some of them are affected by this problem. Waiting for an answer from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instagram had confirmed the issue with API. The resolution will come up.

Here the recent blog post about the issue

http://developers.instagram.com/post/82701625883/api-returning-500-errors-on-specific-ip

Follow up (15/04/2014 17:30 GMT+1): We've been asked by Instagram to send our servers IPs

Follow up (15/04/2014 19:30 GMT+1): Issue is solved. The API reponding within a 500ms

Answer (score 3):

We are having the same issue with API failures at [buzzdeck.com](http://buzzdeck.com), using the Instagram API to collect metrics on user accounts. We're requesting users recent media by page (getting approx 33 items per response even though you can request up to 250), and some page requests work, and some fail - usually the same ones that are failing.

In concordance with what you have seen the issue appears to affect some IP addresses but not others, since some of our servers have been unaffected. We have verified that we're not coming close to API rate limits, and that the Instagram Client app used to make the request makes no difference. We have raised the issue twice with developer support but have had no response from Instagram. Very frustrating!

[EDIT - 15/04/14] Issues have now been resolved by Instagram support, if you're still having trouble it's worth contacting them with the specific IP addresses from which you're making requests

Answer (score 2):

We are running an Instagram API based website on Hetzner since 2011 and experienced this issue once before, solved by contacting Instagram Dev Help center.

Currently having same CURL error with HTTP 500 response.
Already contacted again, about a week ago, and said that they are investigating the issue.

Still digging for the solution, and wish to know what causes it.

**Possible reasons:**

- Two many requests in a short period of time.
- You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id overall. Practically, this means you should (when possible)
  authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a
  given user.

Comment: thanks for the reply! we're partially excluded those two reasons since from the other IP network it works just fine. Maybe our account was compromized and is used by some one else. So I insist that there is something behind instagram, unfortunatelly we donnot have any meens to check the number of requests per second is done with our credentials (I mean the graph) and in case we want to change the credentials if some suspicious activity is observed!

Comment: OK, I've migrated the website do other hosting and now it works smoothly, not even single error of this type. I've reseted the secret via http://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/